# Handling unique constraint error and trying to auto generate a unique value upto n times using a loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, insert-update, unique-constraint

I'm trying to insert a auto generated value into a table. If there is a unique constraint error, I want to get a new value and insert the latest value into the table. I want to try to generate the unique value for up to 10 times before throwing the unique constraint error.

This is what I have so far.

```
BEGIN
    autoGenValue := x
FOR i in 1..10 LOOP
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO mainTbl(A,
                   B, 
                   C)
      VALUES(autoGenValue,
               b,
               c ) 
    EXCEPTION
          WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
            THEN
                SELECT lpad(NVL(MAX(SUBSTR(A, -2)), '00')+1,4,'0')
                INTO maxSeq
                FROM RecvTbl

                SELECT car_id||maxSeq
                INTO autoGenValue 
                FROM DUAL;

         WHEN OTHERS THEN
             EXIT;          
     END;
   END LOOP;

    UPDATE RecvTbl
         SET A = autoGenValue 
         WHERE A = x;  
END;
COMMIT;
```

`x` is the initially calculated auto generated value which I try to insert to the `mainTbl`. If there is a unique constraint error I follow some required logic (simplified here) to get the required unique value. I try this for 10 times (if required). Exit when there is no unique constraint error and update `recvTbl` also with the value as I need it for future calculation.

With my code  I've noticed that the value was being incremented after inserting into the `mainTbl` even when there was no unique constraint error and the value inserted in `recvTbl` was an incremented value instead of the value in the `mainTbl`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you are really doing wrong is **not using a sequence**. This may be an entertaining exercise but this is not something you should put into Production. It won't scale and it won't work in a multi-user environment.

Comment: I did not use a sequence because car_id prefix used to generate the autoGenValue is changed everyday. and max seq starts from 0001 everyday. the car_id is also of two different types for two different formats but all the ID's generated go to the same table. Considering all that I chose this way. I simplified all that logic when asking the question here.

Comment: Then you should use a code control table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have no exit on success.....

You exit the loop if there is any ERROR other than DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX but continue the loop if the insert succeeds.

So the next time through the loop you will get a DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX error and increment.

You could use something like the below (untested), to set a success variable and then exit the loop as soon as it is true.

```
BEGIN
autoGenValue := x;
v_success := false;
FOR i in 1..10 LOOP
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO mainTbl(A,
                   B, 
                   C)
      VALUES(autoGenValue,
               b,
               c ) ;
      v_success := true;
    EXCEPTION
          WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
            THEN
                SELECT lpad(NVL(MAX(SUBSTR(A, -2)), '00')+1,4,'0')
                INTO maxSeq
                FROM RecvTbl

                SELECT car_id||maxSeq
                INTO autoGenValue 
                FROM DUAL;

     WHEN OTHERS THEN
     EXIT;          
     END;
     if v_success = true then
       exit;
     end if;
   END LOOP;

    UPDATE RecvTbl
         SET A = autoGenValue 
         WHERE A = x;  
END;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Yes, The issue was not having EXIT on success. I was under the impression 'WHEN OTHERS' would include that along with other exceptions.

Why do you think it was exiting the loop after the second iteration? I noticed the value in RecvTbl to be just +1 of the value in MainTbl. I would expect it to exit after 10 iterations so the value should be +10 the value in MainTbl.